# Send extra parameters in stripe checkout

Tags: node.js, woocommerce, stripe-payments, next.js

I am using Next.js, Node.js and woocommerce for my cart and when I checkout and send the session back I see all my order details but product ID is one that stripe has generated and not the woocommerce product ID. I need the woocommerce ID because after successfully receiving the payment via stripe, I want to save the order to woocommerce which I can't do without the product ID.

I have looked up if you can send a custom parameter with the line items but I can't find anything and I don't know if it would even be returned by the stripe session.

Node.js code where I would want to send the woocomerce product ID which would then be sent back to me in the session. I could try submit to woocommerce here but then if the order doesn't go through I have an order in woocommerce that didn't actually go through on stripe.

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'T-shirt',
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'http://localhost:4242/success.html',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4242/cancel.html',
  });

  res.json({ id: session.id });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to be per line item/product, then you should include it as `metadata` within the `product_data` ([API ref](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_t8ZJG3cZ1c1O45)):

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [{
    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',
      product_data: {
        name: 'T-shirt',
        metadata: {
          custom_product_id: 'myid_123'
        }
      },
      unit_amount: 2000,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'http://localhost:4242/success.html',
  cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4242/cancel.html',
});
```

Of course if you only need a single value for the session you can also send `metadata` on the [session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) itself or the [payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata).

**Update: Retrieving the line items**

To inspect this product-level `metadata` you'll need to retrieve the session. Note that `line_items` are an *includable* attribute ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=python#checkout_session_object-line_items)) - they are not returned by default. You have to specify them using [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects), and more you'll need to [deeply expand](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#multiple-levels) the `product` objects:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
  'cs_test_123',
  { 
    expand: ['line_items.data.price.product']
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried exactly as you have it where I put the metadata in the product data but when I check the log I don't see it there.

Comment: What do you mean you don't see it? Don't see it where? You will need to retrieve the session and use expansion to include the line items. If you set the `metadata` on the session you'll get that with webhook events. I'll edit my answer to show retrieving this.